# how to use getBytes method to send the entire json message

Tags: java, json, udp

I want to sending data using byte format in UDP protocol,
I have posted part of the java code. I have created a Json object jo, and jo.getBytes() give me error, so I convert jo to String first and then call getBytes() method. and send the packet later.

I am trying to print out the sendData: here is what it prints: [B@26f50154

but I am expecting a whole json message. Help, please.

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("type", "inst");
    jo.put("inst", "send data");
    jo.put("counter", counter);
    //System.out.println(jo);
    counter++;
    sendData = jo.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 4144);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    System.out.println(sendData);
```

Comment: It looks like the `toString()` method is returning the memory location used by the JSONObject instead of the contents.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it. But why is that? I have tried to print out jo, and I get the whole JSON message.

Comment: OK, problem solved. sendData does send the whole json message. I can receive the whole message at the server end. However, system.out.println method would just print out the memory location.